# How can you use the @cache_page decorator with Django class based views?

Tags: python, django

The only method that seems to be working is adding the decorator in urls.py which is ugly.

Is there any way to apply this decorator in the view?

```
class HomeView(View):
    @method_decorator(cache_page(60 * 60))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(HomeView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've tried the above but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `method_decorator` to decorate the view's `dispatch()` method, according to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class). The most succinct way is like this:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import ListView

@method_decorator(cache_page(60*60), name='dispatch')
class MyListView(ListView):
    # Your view code here.
```

Answer (score 2):

use it in urls.py

```
url(r'^home_url/?$', cache_page(60*60)(HomeView.as_view())),
```

Comment: I'd prefer  to not use urls.py as I said in my first line "The only method that's seems to be working is adding the decorator in urls.py which is ugly."

Answer (score 1):

The method_decorator approach should work just fine (we are using it in our project). Are you sure this is the problem?

this is the code we are using (with names changed) - seems like yours

```
class MyClassView(CommonMixin, View):
    @method_decorator(cache_page(60*60, cache='cache1'))
    def get(self, request):
                .....
```

Comment: Well when I add the decorator in urls.py I see files being created in my cache folder (that I defined in settings.py) but when I use the method_decorator as in my example above no file is created so I assume it does not work. (I did restarted the dev server after every change that I made in the code)

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a snippet that works for you?

Comment: @daniels it seems like your code, but I've added it in the answer with names changed.

Comment: Still doesn't work... No idea what the issue could be... I also don't get any error or anything in the console. It's just that the files are not created in the cache folder while if I do this in urls.py they are. Using latest version of Django 1.8.6

Answer (score 1):

Let us say we want to cache the result of the ***myView*** view -

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
@cache_page(60 * 15)
def myView(request, year, month):
    text = "Displaying articles of : %s/%s"%(year, month)
    return HttpResponse(text)
```

and urls.py will be

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',url(r'^articles/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<year>\d{4})/', 'myView', name = 'articles'),)
```

Comment: How can we cache the queryset used in the view by the use of this decorator ? I am failing to do so. If it cache the result of this view, what will be the key under which it is stored ? Please answer both the questions.

Comment: Please follow the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/optimization/#understand-querysets. These would solve your problem.